# Find the inverse function of $f(x)= \sqrt{x-3}+8$ for the domain $[3, \infty)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the inverse function of $ f(x) = \sqrt{x-3} +8$ for the domain $[3, \infty)$

I need to find the Domain and the equation of the ${{f}^{-1}}(x)$, which is the inverse.

**Domain**
I plugged in some numbers to find the range of $f(x)$ The points I came up with are (3,8),(7,10), (12,11)

The Domain then of the inverse is the range of the first function, which is $[8,\infty)$  This answer was accepted.

**Equation**  (this is the part I have wrong)
To find the equation of the inverse I switch around the x and y values and then solve for x.
$$x= \sqrt{y-3}+8$$ $$x-8= \sqrt{y-3}$$ $$(x-8)^2=y-3$$ $$x^2-16x+64=y-3$$ $$x^2-16x+67=y$$ $${{f}^{-1}}(x)=x^2-16x+67 \phantom1 for \phantom1 the \phantom1 domain \phantom1 of \phantom1 [8, \infty)$$

When I plug in the points (8,3), (10,7), and (11,12) the equation appears to work but the practice test I have says it is wrong.

Am I writing the equation wrong because the domain is restricted? Can I have the $x^2$ term in the answer?

Comment: Your answer looks right.

Comment: Your work is correct.

Comment: An equivalent way of writing your answer is $f^{-1}(x) = (x - 8)^2 + 3, x \geq 8$.

Comment: N.F. Taussig, I didn't know that would be an equivalent statement.  More like I would never have thought of that.  Thank you for your insight.